# Image scraper is not downloading images

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making a Image scraper to scrape images from the web. My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

search = input("Search for:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    img.save("./scraped_images/" + title, img.format)
```

The code is not downloading images off the web. Instead, it is giving me this: Process finished with exit code 0. Can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

search = input("Search for:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "img_cont hoff"})
links=[i.img for i in links]
print(links)
for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["src"])
    title = item.attrs["src"].split("/")[-1]
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    img.save("./scraped_images/" + title, img.format)
```

I didn't find any class called `thumb`.
So  I got all the divs and extracted the images which are immediately next to the `div`s